# What is float64?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many ROS message uses the date type float64 so  I decided to use this type in my code but I have this error:

```
   error: ‘float64’ does not name a type
             private: float64 direction_x_;
                      ^
```

I cannot find out the definition of float64. Anyone can tell me what files I should include to find out this data type definition?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205541/what-is-float64?/) by [abcgarden](https://answers.ros.org/users/14016/abcgarden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2015-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dan's answer is correct for describing what a float64 is.

If you want to get rid of the error you are seeing you probably need to have the following in your source (or header) file:

```
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>
```

and change your variable declaration to:

```
std_msgs::Float64 direction_x_;
```

Check out the [std_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs) and [float64](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float64.html) wiki pages. You may also need to add `std_msgs` to your `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` files in your package.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abcgarden](https://answers.ros.org/users/14016/abcgarden/) on 2015-03-21**:
Thank you @Dan, @Thomas. Actually, these two answers combine to be the best answer. But in the std_msgs/Float64 there is one filed "float64 data". It seems that the initial float64 is defined elsewhere. What's the source?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [msg wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields) has a table showing what message types are deserialized to in Python and C++. Specifically, float64 is a double (C++) or float (Python).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-06-30**:
Thak you [Dan Lazewatsky](http://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/), this is the best answer.

**Comment by [Bo Shang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31311/bo-shang/) on 2017-08-25**:
This info helps.

**Comment by [Amos](https://answers.ros.org/users/34051/amos/) on 2018-03-16**:
This is the best answer.